# GraphQL Unique Endpoint

Tags: graphql

Having a play around with graphQL at the moment and getting quite familiar. Apologies if this is a silly question but would it be possible to create a unique endpoint that could be used outside of graphQL?

For example I have been playing with the SpaceX endpoint whereby I have set up a UI to allow users select the data points they want. Is there a way I can extract this endpoint so that a user could cURL it in say terminal and see the same results? Or does everything have to be contained within graphQL playground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. GraphQL is only a query launguage, a set of tools to operate over a single endpoint. All you really need to make a GraphQL query is a HTTP request

With a query like this:

```
{
  users {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

cURL would look like this:

```json
curl --request POST \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"query":"query{users { id name }}"}' \
https://yourdomain.com
```

Comment: Ah fantastic, does GraphQL offer this output anywhere or is is a build your own based on the query? Would this work if you stitched two APIs together?